# Alpine JS is there any way to get transition working in "template" tags?

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am trying to create a simple Alpine component (I'm using Laravel Livewire with Alpine JS) that has a list of items that should only show 3 at a time. Clicking on previous or next buttons should hide the current 3 displaying items and show the next/previous three items from the list. When the items showing update I would like a simple transition (x-transition) to work.

I think that the problem is when using x-transition in AlpineJS, it doesn't work with the "template" tag (based on what the documentation mentions: https://alpinejs.dev/essentials/templating).

I've only used the "template" tag as that's the only way I currently know to iterate through a list of items.

Is there an alternative method I can use to get it to work?

Here's a simplified version of my current code:

```
<?php
$products = [
    [
        'url' => 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/300x201',
        'title' => 'ITEM ONE'
    ],
    [
        'url' => 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/300x202',
        'title' => 'ITEM TWO'
    ],
    [
        'url' => 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/300x203',
        'title' => 'ITEM THREE'
    ],
    [
        'url' => 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/300x204',
        'title' => 'ITEM FOUR'
    ],
    [
        'url' => 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/300x205',
        'title' => 'ITEM FIVE'
    ],
    [
        'url' => 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/300x206',
        'title' => 'ITEM SIX'
    ],
    [
        'url' => 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/300x206',
        'title' => 'ITEM SEVEN'
    ],
    [
        'url' => 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/300x207',
        'title' => 'ITEM EIGHT'
    ],
    [
        'url' => 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/300x208',
        'title' => 'ITEM NINE'
    ],
    [
        'url' => 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/300x209',
        'title' => 'ITEM TEN'
    ]
];
?>


<div x-data="{
    items: @js($products),
    startIndex: 0,
    endIndex: 2,
}">
    <template x-for="(item, index) in items.slice(startIndex, endIndex + 1)">
        <div x-transition>
            <img :src="item.url" alt="">
            <p x-text="item.title"></p>
        </div>
    </template>

    <button x-show="startIndex > 0" x-on:click="startIndex -= 3; endIndex -= 3;">
        PREV
    </button>

    <button x-show="endIndex < items.length - 1" x-on:click="startIndex += 3; endIndex += 3;">
        NEXT
    </button>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could always output the whole list, like

```
<template x-for="(item, index) in items">
    <div class="item"
         :class="index >= startIndex && index <= endIndex && 'visible'">
        <img :src="item.url" alt="">
        <p x-text="item.title"></p>
    </div>
</template>
```

.. then you can apply all kinds of transitions on the 'visible' class, e.g.:

```
.item {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-out; 

    &.visible {
        position: relative;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```